# Flat Vert.x YAML Config

Tags: yaml, config, vert.x

We're wondering if it possible to flat YAML config object? For example, our config files looks like

```
vertx:
  verticle:
    instance: 1
  metrics:
    options:
      enabled: true
```

And we would like to access to our config values with only one operation, for example:

```
config.getInteger("vertx.verticle.instance")
```

instead of having to do:

```
config.getJsonObject("vertx").getJsonObject("verticle").getInteger("integer")
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Vert.x [supports](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_json_pointers) Json Pointers from RFC6901. You could do:

```
JsonPointer pointer = JsonPointer.from("/vertx/verticle/instance");
Integer instance = (Integer) pointer.queryJson(config);
```

Answer (score 1):

While the API doesn't support it directly, it seems easy enough to implement yourself:

```java
public class FlatConfig {
    private final JsonObject root;

    public FlatConfig(JsonObject root) {
        this.root = root;
    }

    private JsonObject walk(String[] path) {
        JsonObject cur = root;
        // skip last element since it contains the value
        for (int i = 0; i < path.length - 2; i++) {
            cur = cur.getJsonObject(path[i]);
        }
        return cur;
    }

    public Integer getInteger(String path) {
        final String[] splitPath = path.split(".");
        return walk(splitPath).getInteger(splitPath[splitPath.length - 1]);
    }
}
```

You can add other methods for retrieving other types as necessary.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I would prefer this approach to flat a JsonObject to another JsonObject. Here's a proposition: https://github.com/georocket/georocket/blob/master/georocket-common/src/main/java/io/georocket/util/JsonUtils.java

Comment: Sure. If you change the generated structure of Vert.x config, I would question why you're using that API at all. I mean, you could just load the configuration into a POJO using SnakeYAML and then be able to access it with `config.vertx.verticle.instance`…

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your question. My use case is :
 - reading config using `ConfigRetriever`
 - use read config to `DeploymentOptions` to deploy verticles
 - access config properties inside verticles.

Comment: I don't really know the vert.x API, you probably know better what you're doing. My point was that for the use case of easily accessing values inside a YAML file, this approach is not ideal. If you need the JsonObject elsewhere for API calls, it is of course justified.